# jQuery longclick fires on table and others buttons in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table structure:

```
<table class="table table-datatable table-custom dataTable" id="basicDataTable" aria-describedby="basicDataTable_info" style="width: 1732px;">
    <thead>
       ...some tr...
    </thead>
    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
         <tr class="odd" id="1">
             <td class=" sorting_1" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">1</td>
             <td class="" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">My Custom string</td>
             <td class>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete row-delete" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-cogs-remove fa-2x"></i></button>
                 <button type="button" id="row-restart" class="btn btn-success row-restart" title="Restart"><i class="fa fa-cogs-refresh fa-2x"></i></button>
             </td>
         </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need when i press long click (say more that 1seconds on id "row-restart" button to fire message....i added this javascript code that when is longclick more that 1second on button#row-restart to fire message..but problem is if i click on another button (Delete) or clicking on table it fires every time...here is my try using javascript:

```
        /* DEFINE - variables */
        var start = 0;

        /* RESTART - long click */
        $('#basicDataTable').on('mousedown', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {
            console.log('long click...')
            /* DEFAULT - disable event */
            e.preventDefault();
            window.type = 1;
            start = new Date().getTime();
        }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
            /* DEFAULT - disable event */
            e.preventDefault();
            if (new Date().getTime() >= (start+1000)) {
                window.type = 2;
                $('#basicDataTable button#row-restart').click();
            }
        }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
            window.type = 1;
            start = 0;
        });
```

So how can i specify only to make longclick on button Restart? (id="row-restart")?

UPDATE:

I have two same event triggers for same button id maybe this is problem?

```
$('#basicDataTable').on('click', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {
            /* DEFAULT - disable event */
            e.preventDefault();
})

$('#basicDataTable').on('mousedown', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {

})
```

You see that common is the same button id '#basicDataTable' and 'button#row-restart' but different is only click and mousedown..maybe jQuery misunderstand this and fires event on every table row and different button i click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors and your help here i finally got it working:

the solution is to add this to existing comparation:

```
&& start !== 0
```

so the final code in javascript is this:

```
 /* DEFINE - variables */
    var start = 0;

    /* RESTART - long click */
    $('#basicDataTable').on('mousedown', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {
        console.log('long click...')
        /* DEFAULT - disable event */
        e.preventDefault();
        window.type = 1;
        start = new Date().getTime();
    }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        /* DEFAULT - disable event */
        e.preventDefault();
        if (new Date().getTime() >= (start+1000) && start !== 0) {
            window.type = 2;
            start = 0;
            $('#basicDataTable button#row-restart').click();
        }
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        window.type = 1;
        start = 0;
    });
```

And now it fires on row-restart button and does not trigger this on clicking on table or others buttons..works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your jquery

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: i added it in above example before e.preventDefault() but problem is the same when i click on table or another button it fires message...so where do i really need to put this e.stopPropagation() in code...before or after e.preventDefault() or another place?

Answer (score 1):

try this but it's not recommended because the table will be dynamic so Id of Button will be changed into dynamically

```js
$(function(){
var start = 0;
$('#row-restart').on('mousedown', function(e) {
            //console.log('long click...')
            /* DEFAULT - disable event */
            e.preventDefault();
            window.type = 1;
            start = new Date().getTime();
        }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
            window.type = 1;
            start = 0;
        }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
            /* DEFAULT - disable event */
            e.preventDefault();
            if (new Date().getTime() >= (start+1000)) {
                window.type = 2;
                $('#basicDataTable #row-restart').click();
              alert("long press");
            }else{
              alert("short press");
            }
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-datatable table-bordered table-custom dataTable" id="basicDataTable" aria-describedby="basicDataTable_info" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        ...
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
         <tr class="odd" id="1">
             <td class=" sorting_1" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">1</td>
             <td class="" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">My Custom string</td>
             <td class>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete row-delete" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-cogs-remove fa-2x">Delete</i></button>
                 <button type="button" id="row-restart" class="btn btn-success row-restart" title="Restart"><i class="fa fa-cogs-refresh fa-2x">Restart</i></button>
               
             </td>
         </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to use this: $('#basicDataTable').on('mousedown', 'button#row-restart', function(e) { to add path 'button#row-restart' so that alert fires when i click that button but the problem is when i click on table or another button it fires too..i think i need to put different path...so if you could rewrite above to trigger with this function posted here and with path to that button...